# PHP Get random paragraph

Tags: php, html, scripting, random, get

Anyone know how to get a random set of lines from a text file?

I want to get a set of 3 lines with 
`<br>`
on the front of each and display them through html.

example:

```
set 1
<br>Hi
<br>what's your name
<br>goodbye

set 2
<br>stack
<br>overflow
<br>hi there
```

set 3,4,5....

Choose one random set and display it.
The sets of lines would be stored in a text file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are sets always separated by blank line ?

Comment: An exact example of the file is required if you want someone to devise a parser for you. Are the sets really separated as you show?

Comment: No they are not, the issue has been solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to create a single array comprised of sub-arrays of a specified size:

```
$fileArr = file('someFile.txt');

// randomize the array
$lines = array_rand($fileArr, 3);

// break it into a single array comprised of arrays of three elements
$chunks = array_chunk($lines, 3);

// read out values of each sub-array
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo $chunk[0] . '<br />';
    echo $chunk[1] . '<br />';
    echo $chunk[2] . '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all the possibilities in an array and then us array_rand() I guess.

Comment: any ideas on how to do that specifically? I know very little PHP.

Comment: The online php documentation is a good place to start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 0):

If the chunks in the text file are always split by the blank line you can ready the file into a single string then split by \n\n.  Then from there grab a random element from that array.