# Php Array explode , implode, shuffle

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to make a very fast function to create a random paragraph .

So I thought , the best way would be to take an existing one , explode, shuffle, and implode .

```
 $content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation .';

   $content = explode(" ", $content);
   shuffle ($content);
   $content = implode(" ", $content);
```

It works, but It produced 2 questions in my mind .

1 - why is this not working : ?

```
   $content = explode(" ", $content);
   $content = shuffle ($content);
   $content = implode(" ", $content);
```

and this does work :

```
   $content = explode(" ", $content);
   shuffle ($content);
   $content = implode(" ", $content);
```

2 - how to randomly define a number of words to drop from the array

(in order to create a random length / number of words ? )

** UPDATE I **

First of all , thanks to all the comments answers !

I ended up with this :

```
   $content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

   ';
   $rand_y = rand(1, 5);// rand number for the loop
   for ($b=1; $b<=$rand_y; $b++) { // repeat random times (to create paragraphes)
   $content = explode(' ', $content);
   $count = count($content) ; // word count - otherwise can return error
   $rand_x = rand(40,$count); // min 20 words , max = word count in paragraph
   $rnd = array_rand($content, $rand_x); // answer from @bsdnoobz
   $content = implode(' ', array_intersect_key($content, array_flip($rnd)));
}
```

1- I added the count() because without it i could get an error if the rand number is bigger than the word count.

> "Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the
>   array"

(actually it is strange that PHP does not automtically ignore such an error - but nevermind .)

2- I did not find a simple way to add a paragraph separator (carriege return or new line) to create more than one . so i used a simple *"for"* loop. it turns out that adding the carriege return inside the $content$ itself will work ! **(I would like to know why , i think it is being counted as part of the array! )**

Anyhow - I know it is a primitive way, and not what many php gurus would choose ,- but I learned a lot , and that is the most important thing - thanks to all !

Comment: `shuffle()` returns a boolean based on whether the shuffle was successful.  So in the first example, `$content` is no longer an array after line 2.

Comment: If you want an other approach, have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695981/php-get-random-paragraph

Comment: And for #2, I'd probably define a function that returns a boolean , returning true with the same distribution that I wanted to let words "stay".  Then use `array_filter()`, specifying my function as the callback parameter.

Comment: @ÉrikRykDesjardins - thanks for the link, I already saw it before :-) I was looking to do myself something simple that suits my un-existing capabilities :-) but thats the way to learn ! thanks .

Comment: @jedwards - regarding comment I - If after line 2 $content is not an array , so how can this non-array be shuffled ? I guess it is semantics, but i just want to understand . And regarding comment II - I will try to understnad what you say and look into the array_filter() function . I am a total novice to PHP and know only the very basics .. Right now I have no Idea how to do it - nor do I fully Understand what you say , but I will try now . Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: @ObmerkNinenine, since I can't post code in a comment, I'll add an answer that has uses `array_filter()` in a moment.

Comment: Regarding you last edit and your question about whether the carriage returns in your `$content` are becoming elements of the array, the answer is they are.  You're `exploding()` not on whitespace in general, but specifically a space. If you had the string "`No\nSpaces\nHere`", `explode()` would result in an array of length 1, not of 3 like you might expect.  If you want "explode" a string based on whitespace in general, consider `$b = preg_split("/\s/", $a);`.

Comment: Thanks again . actually I did wanted the carriege return, and adding 5 of them at the end of the paragraph helped me to divide it randomly . the last code I pasted was producing a random amount of paragraphed with random length just as I wanted :-) even with a very primitive and ugly code thanks to the fact that the "inline" carriage return was in fact counted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shuffle()` will randomize the array argument, but it returns a boolean. You can use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) to pick one or more random entries from an array.

```
$content = explode(' ', $content);
$rnd = array_rand($content, 5);
$content = implode(' ', array_intersect_key($content, array_flip($rnd)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I was talking about regarding `array_filter()`.

```
<?php
$content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?';

function drop_word($word)
{
    $drop_percent = 20;  # I want there to be a 20% chance that I drop the word.
    if(rand(0,99) < $drop_percent)
    {
        printf("Dropping %s\n", $word);
        return false;           # Drop the word by returning false
    }
    else
    {
        return true;            # Keep the word by returning true
    }
}


$word_array  = explode(" ", $content);

shuffle($word_array);   # $word_array is now shuffled
printf('$word_array has %d elements.'."\n", count($word_array));
$filtered_word_array = array_filter($word_array, "drop_word");
printf('$filtered_word_array has %d elements.'."\n", count($filtered_word_array));
$filtered_content = implode(" ", $word_array);
echo "\n";
echo "New paragraph:\n";
echo $filtered_content;

/*
== OUTPUT ==

$word_array has 199 elements.
Dropping exercitation
Dropping dolore
Dropping molestiae
Dropping sint
Dropping enim
Dropping dolorem
Dropping est,
Dropping ipsum
Dropping laboris
Dropping eu
Dropping aut
Dropping ipsa
Dropping consequatur,
Dropping nisi
Dropping cupidatat
Dropping aut
Dropping Nemo
Dropping fugiat
Dropping amet,
Dropping enim
Dropping proident,
Dropping ut
Dropping labore
Dropping irure
Dropping fugiat
Dropping magni
Dropping consequat.
Dropping quia
Dropping fugit,
Dropping voluptatem
Dropping ea
Dropping Ut
Dropping Neque
Dropping anim
Dropping sed
Dropping laborum.
Dropping in
Dropping exercitationem
$filtered_word_array has 161 elements.

New paragraph:
aperiam, adipisci deserunt eiusmod veniam, voluptas dolor tempora exercitation mollit adipisicing numquam est voluptatem. sit Duis porro sit nulla voluptatem ab dolore molestiae sint beatae tempor natus totam enim quisquam dolorem laboriosam, dicta est, in ipsum qui laboris unde id sed incidunt ea reprehenderit quae nihil autem accusantium nesciunt. vel ea quaerat qui ut ex ratione sequi Lorem pariatur? suscipit eu enim Ut quo aut dolor ut sit pariatur. aspernatur quasi commodo ut ipsa consequatur, ipsam aute quia quia qui sunt elit, nisi sed cupidatat iste aliquid esse nisi labore consectetur, iure modi esse velit et doloremque ad quia aut velit, ipsum consequuntur Quis ut eum Nemo nulla eum illo cillum ullamco fugiat ullam dolore qui minima in voluptas amet, rem Excepteur enim proident, quam ad et qui consectetur ex dolore ut dolores quis eius velit aliqua. magna reprehenderit nostrud occaecat labore inventore in eos irure aliquam sit architecto fugiat magni consequat. incididunt quia fugit, illum aliquip corporis Sed voluptatem sunt eaque non error omnis ea Ut vel Neque culpa voluptate dolorem minim anim do nostrum odit sed veniam, perspiciatis laborum. amet, veritatis non explicabo. voluptate officia dolor quis consequatur? voluptatem commodi et in 

 vitae exercitationem magnam laudantium,
 */
```

I left the callback function, `drop_word()` verbose for ease of understanding.  Also, I threw in some `printf()` statements to show what was going on.  You'd want to remove those if you were to actually do something like this.

Also, this is another method that might be a bit easier:

```
<?php
$content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 

 Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?';

$drop_percent = 0.2;    # A decimal number representing the percentage of words you want to drop
                        # 0.2 = 20% (Must be between 0.0 and 1.0)

$word_array  = explode(" ", $content);

shuffle($word_array);   # $word_array is now shuffled
printf('$word_array has %d elements.'."\n", count($word_array));
$filtered_word_array = array_slice($word_array, 0, count($word_array) * (1-$drop_percent));
printf('$filtered_word_array has %d elements.'."\n", count($filtered_word_array));
$filtered_content = implode(" ", $word_array);
echo "\n";
echo "New paragraph:\n";
echo $filtered_content;

/*

== OUTPUT ==

$word_array has 199 elements.
$filtered_word_array has 159 elements.

New paragraph:
et ratione exercitationem eaque consequatur, labore ea ea fugiat ullamco illum ab numquam quia ut eum voluptatem. nulla consequatur? vitae qui non nesciunt. ipsum ad incidunt voluptatem inventore enim consequat. in incididunt voluptatem eos ipsam minima laboris Nemo ut quia quia in sit quam sunt est cillum ea reprehenderit dolor aspernatur voluptas in aut sit nisi adipisci et nostrum anim dolore perspiciatis magni doloremque qui laudantium, labore id amet, eius voluptas Lorem officia esse autem tempora ex omnis do dolore consectetur, iste Ut laborum. laboriosam, natus aliquid dolor amet, velit sed nihil sit cupidatat non porro minim vel sequi adipisicing aut quo quae dolorem irure enim culpa ut quaerat est, qui nulla ullam veniam, sed quasi consequuntur in veniam, occaecat molestiae fugiat quia qui iure veritatis architecto ad voluptate magna suscipit voluptate et vel accusantium modi dolorem pariatur. ex aliquip explicabo. tempor quis beatae velit commodo magnam sit aliquam sint illo error unde aliqua. dolor nisi sunt eum Ut consectetur 

 aperiam, qui Quis exercitation aute voluptatem eu odit nostrud sed elit, Neque corporis eiusmod ut quisquam esse ut ipsum quis ipsa pariatur? Excepteur velit, dolores reprehenderit deserunt Duis rem proident, totam Sed dicta enim commodi fugit, mollit dolore

 */
```

The major difference between the two is that, with the first, each word will have a 20% chance of being dropped, which may result in different length output arrays each time you run it.  Its possible (although not likely), that no words will be dropped.

With the second, 20% of the words are eliminated.  This is certain.  Which 20% will depend on the random shuffling, but 20% will always be dropped, resulting in equal length output arrays every time.

Comment: Wow ! thanks . this is a bit too complicated for my needs , but non the less - It is a obviously a more sophisticated way to achieve that.and by adding `$drop_percent = mt_rand(0, 99)/100;`to your example it is easy enough to randomize that factor as well.

Comment: Regarding the accept - I would hate to un-accept an already accepted answer by @bsdnoobz , and since I can not accept two of them , I can only upvote answer (and comments)

Comment: @Obmerk, no worries whatsoever -- I posted to answer your question in your comment, not to steal a checkmark. Hope it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Because `shuffle` accept a reference of an array, and return a boolean.
2. You could use `rand()` to get a random number.

Comment: thanks for the reply ! 1 -  like i said in other comments , I am a total novice . It is still not so clear to me what is the difference between the two syntaxes . maybe it is semantics, but I want to understand in order not to re-do the same mistakes .  2- as novice as I am , rand() I know :-) but how to apply it in order to randomly drop words from the said array - that is a different story.

Comment: For sake of overall efficiency, I suggest in cases you need rand(), to use instead use mt_rand(). It is much faster and more random.